# JIBX binding loose xml structure

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, unmarshalling, jibx

I am using the org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalDocument(java.io.Reader rdr) class to unmarshall my xml.

This is my binding map which works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <binding xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <mapping name="md" class="com.mycompany.metadata.JiBXMetadata" ordered="false">
          <value name="alice" field="aliceStr" style="element" usage="optional"/>
          <value name="bob" field="bobStr" style="element" usage="optional"/>
          <value name="carol" field="carolStr" style="element" usage="optional"/>
      </mapping>
  </binding>
```

So if the xml has any of the nodes alice, bob or carol in any order it works just fine. If any of the nodes are missing from the xml it still works just fine. But if there is an extra node in the xml (say steve) then I get a JiBXException.

Is there any way to get the unmarshaller to ignore any nodes which are not in the binding map?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the flexible option may help. Can you try to add flexible attribute to your mappings as below?

```
<binding xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <mapping name="md" class="com.mycompany.metadata.JiBXMetadata" ordered="false">
      <value name="alice" field="aliceStr" style="element" usage="optional" flexible="true"/>
      <value name="bob" field="bobStr" style="element" usage="optional" flexible="true"/>
      <value name="carol" field="carolStr" style="element" usage="optional" flexible="true"/>
  </mapping>
```